# my button in tkinter is not showing the image

Tags: python, tkinter

this code is just an example
code:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
photoImageObj = tk.PhotoImage(file="signout.png")
lab = tk.Label(root, image=photoImageObj).pack()
photoImageObjj = tk.PhotoImage(file="signout.png")
signout_button=tk.Button(root,image=photoImageObjj).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

In this code it is working and output is also working fine.
here is the output:
[image]
but in my real project, where I am using this button with the image is not working.
code:

```
photoImageObj = PhotoImage(file="signout.png")
signout_button=Button(stem,image=photoImageObj).pack()
```

here I haven't pasted my whole code since it is having 50-60 line's of code.
Output:
[image]

so if the same code is working fine, then there is problem in my real project file.
so can anyone help me debug that.

Comment: Is the code in your project inside a function?

Comment: yeah, it is inside a function

Comment: is that the culprit behind this

Comment: Yes it is the "culprit"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an image is inside a function you have to keep reference to the image or it will be garbage collected by python. With the code provided its hard to say, but just try something like:

```py
signout_button = Button(stem,image=photoImageObj)
signout_button.pack() #so that signout_button is not None
signout_button.image=photoImageObj #keeping a reference
```

Alternatively, you could also say `global photoImageObj` on top of function, but its not recommended to use `global`. This question should be marked as a duplicate and closed, but just in-case you dont understand what to do in your "specific case", here is the answer.