# Is using config to change image of button in function wrong?

Tags: python, tkinter

I was making python gui with tkinter
I wanted to change button's image if I push button
But it doesn't work.(I use config)

with some effort I found it work in main code
but still it doesn't work in fucntion that is connected to button

### Here are the codes

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# using by function
def select_precision():
    overheal = image_resize((20, 20), "gui_project/item_simulation/overheal.png")
    runepage_00.config(image=overheal)

def image_resize(size, link):
    image = Image.open(link)
    image = image.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    return image

root = Tk()
root.title()

precision = PhotoImage(file="gui_project/item_simulation/precision.png")
rune00 = PhotoImage(file="gui_project/item_simulation/domination.png")

runepage_precision = Button(root, width=20, height=20,\
     image=precision, command=select_precision)
runepage_00 = Button(root, width=20, height=20, image=rune00)

runepage_precision.pack()
runepage_00.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

### but if I change like this, the config works but I don't know why

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def image_resize(size, link):
    image = Image.open(link)
    image = image.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    return image

root = Tk()
root.title()

precision = PhotoImage(file="gui_project/item_simulation/precision.png")
rune00 = PhotoImage(file="gui_project/item_simulation/domination.png")

runepage_precision = Button(root, width=20, height=20,\
     image=precision, command=select_precision)
runepage_00 = Button(root, width=20, height=20, image=rune00)

# using inside the code
overheal = image_resize((20, 20), "gui_project/item_simulation/overheal.png")
runepage_00.config(image=overheal)

runepage_precision.pack()
runepage_00.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

to make it short

first was

```
def select_precision():
    overheal = image_resize((20, 20), "gui_project/item_simulation/overheal.png")
    runepage_00.config(image=overheal)

runepage_precision = Button(root, width=20, height=20,\
     image=precision, command=select_precision)
runepage_00 = Button(root, width=20, height=20, image=rune00)
```

and second was

```
runepage_precision = Button(root, width=20, height=20,\
     image=precision, command=select_precision)
runepage_00 = Button(root, width=20, height=20, image=rune00)

overheal = image_resize((20, 20), "gui_project/item_simulation/overheal.png")
runepage_00.config(image=overheal)
```

Comment: Probably because it got sweeped by pythons garbage collector. Try keeping a reference to the image. Maybe try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64768327/13382000)

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error? Does it configure the widget incorrectly? Does the program crash?

Comment: @CoolCloud oh I didn't think about that. really thank you.

Comment: @BryanOakley oh I had to put screenshot of that. It means when I push the button, button's image is gone and even I cannot push the button.

Comment: If that question has solved the issue, do mention it.